# Is it really a bad idea to work at a company that misses the mark for perfection once or twice - on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, specific-question

The question [Is it really a bad idea to work at a company that misses the mark for perfection once or twice?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/is-it-really-a-bad-idea-to-work-at-a-company-that-misses-the-mark-for-perfection) was recently posted, and is asking about whether it's good to completely dismiss a company based on one or two bad practices. I really think this is a great question and could lead to some good discussion, but I'm not sure it fits our Q&A format. It seems like it could be closed as too broad or opinion-based (though there are not yet any close-votes at this time).

I would really like to see this question stay open. Are there ways we can improve it to make it more on-topic, or do you think it's okay as is?

Comment: I also had this concern when writing the question. I thought about it for a while, and I wasn't quite sure how to resolve the issue, but thought it was not as serious a case of too-broadiness. I'm definitely open to suggestions and feedback.

Comment: @Emrakul Well so far there's only 1 close vote (and not for broad or opinion-based), so I think you should be okay.

Comment: So it looks like it got closed, which I think is unfortunate.... :(

Comment: @enderland At least it got some good answers and up-votes in the process. Is there a way to edit the question to get it reopened?

Comment: @DavidK any edit or reopen vote puts it into the reopen queue, so that'd be one way?

Comment: It could use a less opinion-y/extreme title.  ("Misses the mark for perfection"? Is that really what's being asked about?)  I ignored the question the first several times I saw it on the front page because of the title, and only read it when it was brought up here on meta.  If you can improve the title (or anything else about it), please do.

Answer (score 1):

I actually think this is a good question. It's a bit long, but the context is clear and it's a good subjective question.

Your problem is slightly less clear but I still think it's a *good* question about navigating interviews. It will also be a useful reference as this sort of thing comes up somewhat often.